# Android: Master-Detail type FilterChooser one screen on phone

Tags: android, android-fragments, master-detail

I am trying to create a screen that looks like this:

[image]

It is a filter chooser screen that allows a user to select from multiple filters to apply to a separate fragment.

Clicking on the images on the left bring up different categories of filter text that can be used and applied from the list on the right.

I am trying to use Master-Detail flow for this, but this is for a phone and I really want this entire item to be on one screen, not separate master and detail screens.

Is there a way to do this with Master-Detail or does anyone have any tips on how I should implement this using a different mechanism?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several possibilities to solve your issue, here are two:

- You can create a custom layout that integrates some Buttons on the  left, a listView on the right and some Buttons at the bottom. But as I understand you, you want to add multiple filters, so it will be better to solve this dynamically:
- You can create a layout that has a `Fragment` on the left and a `listFragment` on the right.

To control the listViews behaviour you can write your own `Adapter` (e.g. `BaseAdapter`). To customize your listItems you have to override the `getView()` method. You also have to read [this article about ViewHolder](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html#ViewHolder) to ensure a good performance of your `listView`.

Comment: Thanks for the help, that pretty much worked, but I ended up using a viewpager on the left because it helped with some tasks.